# Wordpress image resize quality could be better

Tags: wordpress, image, image-resizing

I do use the automatic resize function of wordpress and have already set the image quality for jpgs to a much higher quality via the `functions.php` file like so:

```
add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg)
    {
        return 90;
    }
);
```

However, the resulting image quality is still not very good. The pictures could need a sharpening pass or a different resize algorithm.

I did not find any way to tell wordpress to use a different algorithm so far - does anyone know a hook or something similar to increase the quality?

Comment: if possible you can use this plugin check here https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-resized-image-quality/screenshots/

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is paste the following code in your theme’s functions.php file or your site-specific plugin.

```
function gpp_jpeg_quality_callback($arg)
{
return (int)100;
}

add_filter('jpeg_quality', 'gpp_jpeg_quality_callback');
```

Or

```
add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', create_function( '', 'return 100;' ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change from admin panel .
Setting >> media >> here you can add you size for images.

for thumbnail,small ,large images .

Comment: the image quality is not the same as the size - I did define the sizes in my functions.php-file.

Comment: `add_action( 'jpeg_quality', 'function_image_sizes' );
 
function function_image_sizes() {
    add_image_size( 'article-image', 300, 300 );
    add_image_size( 'article-image-cropped', 300, 300, true ); // this will force the image size to 300x300 by cropping it
}`